# Вывести имя пользователя в битриксе

Tags: битрикс

В битриксе есть компонент "news.list", как под каждой статьей вывести имя пользователя, добавившего эту статью? На одном сайте нашёл решение, что можно поймать ID пользователя с помощью $arResult["CREATED_BY"], и дальше двигаться от него. Однако, я не нашёл такого поля в массиве -_-

Answer (score 0):

В параметрах компонента можно указать список полей элементов инфоблока.

Через визуальный редактор:
[image: Поля]

Через код:

```
"FIELD_CODE" => array("CREATED_BY", "CREATED_USER_NAME")
```